# Tabulator ajaxURL adding a question mark to end

Tags: django, wagtail, tabulator

I am using wagtail/django for a project and am trying to do ajax calls to tabulator. I currently have this

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    ajaxURL:"http://localhost:8000/api/v2/people/?fields=*", //ajax URL
    ajaxConfig:{
        method:"get", //set request type to Position
        headers: {
            "Content-type": 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //set specific content type
        },
    },
    height:"311px",
    layout:"fitColumns",
    placeholder:"No Data Set",
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"name", sorter:"string", width:200},
        {title:"Date", field:"date", sorter:"string"},
    ],
});

table.setData();
```

But my debug console in the browser has

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/api/v2/people/?fields=*?
"message": "fields error: unexpected char '?' at position 1"
```

Why is a question mark being added to the end? I can replicate the same error if I add a question mark to the end in the Django Rest Page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` is being added because that's the standard way to pass additional parameters to the URL, and apparently Tabulator isn't checking whether `ajaxURL` has one already. You can fix this by moving the `fields` parameter to `ajaxParams`, where it will be combined with any other parameters that Tabulator might pass:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    ajaxURL:"http://localhost:8000/api/v2/people/",
    ajaxParams: {'fields': '*'},
    ajaxConfig:{
        method:"get", //set request type to Position
        headers: {
            "Content-type": 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //set specific content type
        },
    },
    height:"311px",
    layout:"fitColumns",
    placeholder:"No Data Set",
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"name", sorter:"string", width:200},
        {title:"Date", field:"date", sorter:"string"},
    ],
});
```

Comment: Which version of Tabulator are you using? version 4.4 and up should be able to cope with a ? in the URL

Comment: I am using tabulator 4.5.3